# Window.open() as modal, enablePrivilege doesn't work

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, window.open

I have a problem using window.open() in my software:

I need a modal window, but using window.open() with modal option i need to enable `"UniversalBrowserWrite"`, but the enablePrivilege in js in deprecated.

What can i use?

this is my code:

```
netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalBrowserWrite");

returnValue = window.open(IR_URL,"","modal=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable,width=1024,height=768");
```

Thank you,

Stefano

Comment: Without using the words "modal window" or "UniversalBrowserWrite", explain what you want the end result to be.

Comment: I just need a substitute for the deprecated method enablePrivilege

Comment: Why?  What are you trying to do?  Stop focusing on a perceived issue and tell us the bigger picture.

Comment: Ok, i'm sorry. I'm trying, in my software, to open a child window, and while it is opened de parent window need to be stopped. This is the Modal behaviour, and it works great whit the method window.showModalDialog. But this method is deprecated, and i found the new method window.open(), but the option modal of this method doesen't work without the "UniversalBrowserWrite" privilege. So is there another way to create a modal window in javascript?

Comment: Okay - what do you mean by "stopped"?  Most standard behavior can be disabled by simply having a modal dialog (by today's standards, not using another window) - a div that covers the current page and then another div that shows a "modal dialog".  If there is code running in the background that needs to be stopped then you stop it in your code.  This is very basic, but what I mean... https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#live-demo